# Why lord Venkateshwara's name is not listed in the avatars of vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, venkateshwara, tirupati

Why is lord [Venkateshwara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara) name not listed in avatar of Vishnu?

Comment: The very first sentence of the Wikipedia article you linked to says "Venkateswara (IAST: Veṅkaṭēśvara), also known as Śrinivasā, Bālāji, Veṅkaṭā, and Veṅkaṭācalapati, is a form of the Hindu god Vishnu."  What more do you want?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan i edited the question.

Comment: there are many names not listed in the classical ten avatars of Vishnu. Those ten names are simply a list of 'popular forms that Lord Vishnu has taken' that's it. There are innumerable forms of Lord Vishnu. Lord Vishnu appears to His devotees whenever the devotees have firm faith and unsullied devotion for His Feet. Listing down every possible form or avatara of Sri Vishnu would be like listing every possible drop of water in the sea. Thank you sir!

Comment: As Sai said, the answer to your question is that simply that the list of ten avatarams is just a list of the ten most prominent ones, not the only ten ones, see my answer in the linked question.

Comment: In the BSB 1.1.20 Shankara has said:

Brahman can take, by will, an illusory form, for the sake of blessing the aspirant. He cites the Mahabharata verse where Krishna, pointing to the visvarupa says to Narada:  His is a form that I have created out of My. Do not know that to be my true nature.'

Even aprAkRta is admitted in the Advaitasiddhi as of prakrti only, if not through the medium of the panchabhUta-s. An aspirant can imagine any kind of dress, ornaments, posture, etc. exploits, etc. to the divine form. There is no limit to that. All forms - Hari, Hara, are of one Brahman alone.

Comment: In my above comment, please read this correction: // He cites the Mahabharata verse where Krishna, pointing to the visvarupa says to Narada: His is a form ...//  His = This...